# Is it a good practice to make constructor explicit

Tags: c++

When designing a public API, is it a good practice to make the constructor as explicit?

```
class A {
public:
    //explicit A(int i){}
    A(int i){}
};

void fun(const A& a) {}

int main() {
    // If I use explicit for A constructor, I can prevent this mistake.
    // (Or shall I call it as feature?)
    fun(10);
}
```

Or shall I allow implicit conversion, to allow user to call my API with less typing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The constructor should be explicit, unless an implicit conversion makes sense semantically (e.g. what is the meaning of converting an `int` to an `A`?). Less typing should not be the criterion to guide that decision. Think about readability (which is the main argument for implicit casting) and how well your code is to understand. An implicit cast that is not intuitive will make readers of the code scratch their heads.

P.S.: I cannot seem to come up with a good example right now, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: example for implicit conversion: anything numberlike (e.g. a bignum library, or a date/time library) – against implicit conversion: just consider the `std::vector` class that can be initialized with an initial size.

Comment: I agree with this. IME there's rarely ever a case where you want implicit casting and if you err on the explicit side, no harm is done by forcing users to a few more keystrokes.

Comment: As an example: implicit conversion from double to complex via `complex(double re, double im = 0)` makes sense, but conversion from int to vector via `vector(int size)` doesn't.

Comment: @Tadeusz: Even if it made sense, I'd advice against it. You forget one `#include`, and your code silently calls the wrong function. Writing `complex(42.0)` is so much easier than debugging late into the night to find such a bug.

Comment: @sbi: and that is why I am a bit wary of the new user-literals feature of C++0x, that one `x` behind your number can completely change its type may be useful... but the hell with readability. I would have preferred aliasing: `using snsc = super::name::space::Create;` which saves keystroke but brings in scoping etc...

Answer (score 8):

Yes, by default any constructor, which can be called with one argument
should be explicit. Following this rule will avoid subtle bugs, which are
extremely hard to find.

Of course, there are exceptions to this rule:

- Implicit conversion might be desireable, if your class has the
  semantics of a wrapper around the one parameter's type.
- Copy constructors should not be explicit (otherwise you loose the
  possibility for pass-by-value calls).

Answer (score 7):

[This](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c++/browse_thread/thread/3e845e305474febe#) is what I found in a resonse from "Daniel Krügler"

> If we would have started to design C++
>   from today on, there  is a good
>   chance, that all constructors and
>   conversion functions  were "explicit"
>   by default, but a user could make the
>   "implicit".  Alas, the time cannot be
>   turned back and we have to live with 
>   the current state. This means that we
>   have to be careful in  regard to
>   implicit constructors (except for the
>   copy/move  constructor). It is a safer
>   rule to make constructors explicit, 
>   where some form of conversion is
>   involved (i.e. any constructor  with
>   an argument type U different from the
>   actual type T).

Comment: @Yan Cheng CHEOK: I guess he is part of the C++ standards committee (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010)

Answer (score 1):

Explicit constructors are used in classes, which consume significant resourses, like memory, construction time etc., to prevent user to create instances of such classes accidentally. It's up to you to decide, whether your class is "heavy" enough to use explicit constructor.

Comment: Accidental casting can be fatal even if the object is not expensive to create.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: accidental casting is your own fault for accidentally typing out a cast. Accidental implicit conversion is the issue here, surely.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the costs involved, both semantically and performance. If the creation of your class is expensive you should prevent it from being instantiated accidentally. If it's a cheap class to create then implicit construction can greatly simplify work for the API user.

Comment: This fails to mention the ambiguities and potentially unwanted, non-sensical conversions that can otherwise happen.