# How C++ is this code working?

Tags: c++

I have a strange bit of code. I must have been hitting my keyboard with my eyes closed because this type of thing is really dumb, but weird thing is, I caught it after the program ran successfully.

> ```
> struct Number{
> private:
>   unsigned long longNumber;
> public:
>
>    Number(unsigned long n)
>    {
>       longNumber = n;
>    }
>
>   unsigned long getReverse()
>   {
>       /*some magic that returns an unsigned long */
>   }
>
>   inline
>   unsigned long getLong()
>   {
>       return longNumber;  
>   }
>   inline
>   static Number add(Number one, Number two)
>   {
>       return Number(one.getLong() + two.getLong());
>   }
> };
>
>
> int main()
> {
>   scanf("%lu", n);
>   Number number = Number(n);
>   number = Number::add(number, number.getReverse());
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

There's more stuff going on in main() of course and Number has few more members and functions, but this is what's important I believe.

If you look in main, you'll see that add() is being passed a Number and an unsigned long, but add() only accepts Number and Number.

What's going on here?

EDIT: added constructor above

Comment: Try making your constructor `explicit` and see if it still compiles.

Comment: Did you forget to mention you have a c'tor for Number? (For example Number::Number(long))

Comment: Having implicit conversion both to and from a class is generally not a good idea. People easily get confused on what conversion the compiler selects.  :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `Number` has a constructor which accepts `unsigned long` the compiler is creating a temporary object of type `Number` from the return value of `number.getReverse()` and passing it to the `add` function. If you don't want such implicit conversion to occur, you need to declare the `Number` constructor as `explicit`.

Comment: Weird stuff.  I'll be sure to mark constructors explicit by default.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an implicit conversion from long to Number.  You're also not showing us all your code or a working segment.

Answer (score 1):

You have left out the constructor that takes a long as an argument.

The second argument to the call: `Number::add(number, number.getReverse())` is being converted to a Number temporary.

Answer (score 1):

As others said, it is because you don't have an explicit constructor. For more details on why a constructor should be explicit or not, [see this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716453/is-it-a-good-pratice-to-make-constructor-explicit)